# Degree - Lexicographic ordering with an example

Tags: combinatorics, monoid, monomial-ideals

Let $X=\{x,y\}$ and $ x>y $ lexicographically. Let consider $X^*$ as a free monoid generated by $X$. We define a monomial ordering on $X^*$ which is compatible with the multiplication of words, due to its definition. Let $deg-lex$ be the  ordering defined on $X^*$.

Then I want to order the following (all monomials of degree 3) by $deg-lex$ ordering. I just want to ask you about the correctness of the way I have already ordered them?

$y^{3} < y^{2}x< yxy <yx^{2} <xy^{2} <xyx<x^{2}y <x^{3}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer looks correct.

A bit of terminology. Since you refer to a free monoid, I would call your order  the [*shortlex order*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortlex_order), also known as *radix*, *length-lexicographic*, *military*, or *genealogical ordering*. The term [*deg-lex*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monomial_order) is rather used for
monomials of a polynomial ring.